# Java Mail - вставка картинки

Tags: java, javamail

Возможно ли вставить картинку в письмо? Если да, то как это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будем считать, что с отправкой писем как таковых через Java Mail разобрались.

Кладёте картинку в аттачмент и ставите аттачменту заголовок ([setContentID](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setContentID(java.lang.String)))

```
Content-ID: <my.image.id>
```

Тело текста делаете text/html и ссылаетесь на картинку следующим образом:

```
<img alt="test" src="cid:my.image.id" />
```

Так ведь по ссылке, которую вы дали именно это и описано внизу.. так что я не понимаю, почему вы решили, что нельзя

Comment: Т.е. получается, что изображение идёт как аттачмент и отображается в самом сообщении?

Comment: Именно так

Answer (score 0):

Можно, конечно. Вот как [здесь описано](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0504.html), например. По сути вы или составляете письмо в HTML и вставляете `<img>` или добавляете аттачмент к письму.

Comment: Допустим, аттачмент, но как этот рисунок вставить в текст в определенное место? И чем это отличается от ссылки на рисунок?

Comment: Если прикреплять аттачментом, то в определенное место вставить уже не выйдет.

Comment: Как это не выйдет? Ещё как выйдет.

Comment: +1. Я подразумевал, впрочем, что если использовать аттачмент, то потому, что по каким-то причинам не использовать HTML.